# Setting Input Element value with javascript function

Tags: javascript, liquid

I have the following html input element

```
<input type="number" name="updates[]" value=MyBlah(var) readonly/>
```

and the following javascript function

```
    function MyBlah(var) {
             return 10;
    }
```

I am receiving this error in the console when the html element tries to render.

"The specified value "MyBlah(product)" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?"

Any Ideas? It may be useful to note that I am trying to use liquid in the javascript function, however I get the error prior to setting up the liquid functionality

Answer (score 1):

This is because HTML is not evaluating the value attribute as a function. It is reading it as a string value and since the input is of type number it does that regex to check if it actually is a number and throws the error when it is not. MyBlah(var) is not of type number.